# Can't quit TrackPopupMenu

Tags: c++, api, winapi, menu

I'm trying to create a popup menu which appear while typing on an edit control to show suggestion. The problem is I can't continue typing as the popup wouldn't disappear. The only way is to click outside the popup. It's every inconvenient if every character you typed you have to click outside to keep writing.

I've tried SetForeGround before calling TrackPopupMenu but it didn't work.

```
if (HIWORD(wParam) == EN_CHANGE)
        {    
           HMENU suggest = CreatePopupMenu();
           WCHAR text[50];
           GetWindowText(tagTxt, text, 50);

            if (wcslen(text) > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Tag.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (wcsncmp(Tag[i].tagName, text, wcslen(text)) == 0)
                        AppendMenu(suggest, MF_STRING, NULL, Tag[i].tagName);

                }

                POINT curPoint;
                GetCursorPos(&curPoint);

                SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);

                UINT code = TrackPopupMenu(suggest,TPM_RETURNCMD | TPM_NONOTIFY, curPoint.x, curPoint.y, 0, hWnd, NULL);
                SendMessage(hWnd, WM_NULL, 0, 0);
            }
         }
```

Comment: Popup menu is the wrong way to implement suggestions. Its modal nature is not suited. Use, for instance, a list box instead. Well, really you should use the built in facilities that the edit control provides: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776884.aspx

Comment: More information on how to implement an [IAutoComplete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776292.aspx) source: [Providing a custom autocomplete source for an edit control](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130923-00/?p=3163) and [Using Microsoft's Auto-Completion Framework](http://www.lebeausoftware.org/articles/bcbj_vol10_num9.1.pdf) from [Lebeau Software: Articles](http://www.lebeausoftware.org/articles.aspx).